# How to split JSON array with multiple separater?

Tags: javascript, appery.io

i having problem with JSON array. Firstly, i have a set of JSON array that retrieved from API like below

```
{
"image_path":[
    "slider.jpg",
    "slider_2.jpg",
    "slider_3.jpg",
    "slider_4.jpg"
],
"name":[
    "KIDCARD Banner",
    "Christmas",
    "Back To School",
    "Chinese New Year"
],
"start_time":[
    "2015-11-24 01:12:04",
    "2015-11-24 04:31:26",
    "2015-11-24 01:11:30",
    "2015-11-29 01:11:07"
],
"end_time":[
    "2020-12-31 01:12:04",
    "2016-01-31 04:31:26",
    "2016-01-20 01:11:30",
    "2016-02-22 01:11:07"
]
}
```

But, i only want to get data in "name" and display it according. I able to split it with var array = title.split("",""); in javascript, but the result that display out is  "Christmas" which i only want Christmas. So i need help to remove the "" on the word. I'm javascript to do it. Thank you.

Comment: What does this have to do with appery.io?

Comment: What is `title`? What are you trying to split, and why?

Comment: How is this related to JSON, which is string-based data interchange format?

Comment: first, i doing it with appery.io and javascript. second, there not title from the API. third, the data is display from API is using JSON format

Comment: If the problem is not related to or specific to appery.io, please remove the tag.

Comment: What is a "deteminer"?

Answer (score 2):

You can get name like this

```
var arr={
"image_path":[
    "slider.jpg",
    "slider_2.jpg",
    "slider_3.jpg",
    "slider_4.jpg"
],
"name":[
    "KIDCARD Banner",
    "Christmas",
    "Back To School",
    "Chinese New Year"
],
"start_time":[
    "2015-11-24 01:12:04",
    "2015-11-24 04:31:26",
    "2015-11-24 01:11:30",
    "2015-11-29 01:11:07"
],
"end_time":[
    "2020-12-31 01:12:04",
    "2016-01-31 04:31:26",
    "2016-01-20 01:11:30",
    "2016-02-22 01:11:07"
]
};

arr.name.forEach(function(i,j){
console.log(i)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing. Have you already parsed the JSON data, or are you treating it like a string? If it's the latter, you should parse it using `JSON.parse`.

Say you've got your set of arrays in `data`, it would look like:

```
var arrays = JSON.parse(data);
var christmas = arrays.name[1];
```

then `christmas` would have the value "Christmas". Or you could iterate over the array using `Array.forEach` or just a standard `for` loop.